# How to texture a marble

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

I have modeled some marbles, shown here in the picture. [image]

But I need to texture it to look like these:
[image]

I have no clue on how to texture these, so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'd suggest to think about how it actually works in real life. You have the transparent marble with something opaque in it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwSbmCW8qVg

Comment: It is probably easier if you don't really "texture" them at all and actually model that little squiggles inside

Comment: @LukeD Hey that's pretty cool, nice results. You could feed a noise texture into its UV vector input to create the distortions. You should post that as an answer

Comment: @LikeD add some kind of noise (or wave) texture to the vectors that control the gradient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: final]

> ***This one is too "heavy" answer to explain it step by step so I'll make
>   an overview of the node setup and if you'll have some questions just
>   ask in comments and I'll expand it.***

### Overview:

Overall it's really simple setup. Think of it as spheres squashed and distorted inside marble (because they exactly are). Spheres are Spherical Gradient, squash is Mapping Node and distortion are nodes named Sine Wave.

> **Don't forget to set in *Render > Light Paths > Volume* - to more than 0! In this example it is set to 4.**

[image: Nodes]

**From Node Setup:**

1. They control how much distorted inside elements are. It is separated for X and Y wave. You can make pretty straight lines with those values or with more waviness.

[image: differences]

2. Those one controls overall width of inside elements.
3. With **Scale** in **Mapping node** you can control how our starting sphere (**Gradient > Spherical**) will be squashed on X, Y and Z axes.
4. This is color for our elements.
5. And lastly (or maybe it should be first) this is starting sphere that is pretty much just manipulated by **Sine Waves** and **Mapping Node**.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Wow, excellent result, worked out much better than I expected. Love the slight translucency of the squiggles.

Comment: I can't find the principle BSDF. I only found the long one. Not the short node. Where would I find that?

Comment: The short one is just hidden long one. Press ctrl+h hovering over it to expand/shrink it.